# How to check for {} value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For some reason in the code below the currentRow.cells returns {}. How can I check for that? I do not want to execute lines if the currentRow.cells returns {}.

```
 currentRow = document.createElement("TR");
 if(currentRow.cells.length > 0) { .. do something }
```

UPDATE 1:

All I want is to check for empty object. if the currentRow.cells is an empty object then do nothing.

Comment: It is an empty object. And the question is not clear

Comment: You're doing `createElement('tr')`.  Won't this make a new `<tr>`, which would be blank?

Comment: @Rocket Yes how can I check for empty object. There are times when it is not blank.

Comment: `currentRow.cells.length === 0`?

Comment: currentRow.cells.length outputs "undefined"

Comment: You can try `currentRow.childNodes.length`.

Comment: I think you should use jquery to manipulate the DOM, if the library is available to you.

Comment: `HTMLTableRowElement#cells` is  an `HTMLCollection`, so it has a `length` property. If the length is 0, it has no cells. It doesn't  return anything, it's not a function.

Comment: If `currentRow.cells` is `undefined`, that means `currentRow` isn't a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2):

I always get an object of type HTMLCollection.

You should be able to then check the length of the collection using code like this:

```
if(currentRow.cells.length != 0) {
    //row and cells exist, work with them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a helper method called [`$.isEmptyObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).

Their code for this is simple:

```
function isEmptyObject( obj ) {
    for ( var name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you don't want to use the whole jQuery library, you can snag this method and drop it somewhere in your own code base!

Comment: Problem is `currentRow.cells` is not a plain object, it's a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLCollection), so this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just answering the question the OP asked: "All I want is to check for empty object."

Comment: "if the currentRow.cells is an empty object"  Unfortunately, this will not be able to check if `currentRow.cells` is an empty object.  All it will do is tell you if `currentRows.cells` is `undefined` or not.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title:

```
function is_empty(obj) {
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

alert(is_empty({})); // true
```

Comment: Problem is `currentRow.cells` is not a plain object, it's a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLCollection), so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`currentRow` is a `<tr>` (or a `HTMLTableRowElement`), and `currentRow.cells` is a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLCollection) (not an Array (`[]`) or an object (`{}`)).

If `currentRow.cells` is undefined, that means that `current` row isn't a `<tr>`, it's another element.

To check if a DOM element is empty, you can use [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.childNodes) (this will *never* be `undefined`).

```
if(currentRow.childNodes.length === 0){
    // empty
}
else{
    // not empty
}
```

Edit: Better yet, you can use [`hasChildNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.hasChildNodes).

```
if(!currentRow.hasChildNodes()){
    // empty
}
else{
    // not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cells` property isn't available in `<tr>` on IE8 and below. A workout is to use `childNodes` as suggested above. The following code checks if `cells` is undefined:

```
var currentRow = document.createElement("TR");
if (typeof currentRow.cells === "undefined") {
    // use currentRow.childNodes
}
else {
    // use currentRow.cells
}
```